# How to create a CDN to store and serve images and videos?

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, architecture, cdn

We have a requirement to store and retrieve content(Audio, Video, Images) quickly. We are not allowed to use Commercial providers like AWS S3 etc.

Any suggestions on how to go about? Challenges I forsee are
a) Storage
b) Fast Retrieval
c) Caching

Would cassandra help in the above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical use case for Cassandra for things like streaming services or media-sharing social apps.

The difference is that the media files are saved in an object store and only the metadata (such as URL of the media file) is stored in Cassandra so you can retrieve information about where the media is stored really quickly.

As a side note, I wanted to warn you that others will likely vote to close your question because it is [soliciting opinions vs a specific software issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers!